# Can't parse a video link from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to get a youtube video link connected to a certain webpage. I've written a script to fetch that link but I've ended up getting an image link instead.

[Webpage address](https://www.groupon.com/deals/maono-massage-and-wellness-1)

I've tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'find the link above'

def get_youtube_link(link):
    res = requests.get(link, headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml' )
    youtube_link = soup.select_one("img[class='sleepy-load'][data-id^='video']")['data-original']
    print(youtube_link )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_youtube_link(url)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
//img.youtube.com/vi/tlgcDTLgNvg/default.jpg
```

As the link is not attached to that video so i could not show here how the link might look like.

This is how that video look like in that page:
[image]

***How can i scrape that video link from that page?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to fetch `//img.youtube.com/vi/tlgcDTLgNvg/default.jpg` here the `tlgcDTLgNvg` is the youtube video id, the youtube link would be

```
video_id = "tlgcDTLgNvg"
youtube_link = https://youtu.be/{}.format(video_id)
```